# CSS - Adding select Dropdown option width wrapping and scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css

I got a select dropdwon as follows

```
   <div style="overflow: auto; max-height: 200px;">
   <select id="ddl-width-wrap">
          <option value="1">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores</option>
          <option value="2">et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est</option>
          <option value="3">laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. </option>
          <option value="4">officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates</option>
          <option value="5">officiis debitis aut rerum</option>
          <option value="6">necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates</option>
          <option value="7">rum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
          <option value="8">sum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
          <option value="9">fum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
          <option value="10">aum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
          <option value="11">rtum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
          <option value="12">rumq rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
          <option value="13">rumer rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
   </select> 
  </div>
```

I would like to wrap the length options to wrap to a new line and have a scroll by y-axis. I tried wrapping the select with a div and styling with overflow to auto and max-height to 200 px but not getting desired result. Can anyone assist on how this can be solved?

Also, I'm not looking for any bootstrap select or other framework options to fix this issue.

Comment: The default select element uses the system's rendering, so other than a few options like the font size, you can't change the way it's presented.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [select2](https://select2.org/), which gives you many options for styling and presentation. This shows you how to implement and override the styles (if desired)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
let sconfig = {
    templateResult: function(data) {
      if (!data.element) {
        return data.text;
      }
      let $element = $(data.element);
      let $wrapper = $('<div></div>');
      $wrapper.addClass('option');
      $wrapper.text(data.text);
      return $wrapper;
    }
  }
  
  $('#ddl-width-wrap').select2(sconfig);
});
```

```css
#ddl-width-wrap {
  width: 400px;
}

.option {
  padding: 15px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select id="ddl-width-wrap">
    <option value="1">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores</option>
    <option value="2">et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est</option>
    <option value="3">laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. </option>
    <option value="4">officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates</option>
    <option value="5">officiis debitis aut rerum</option>
    <option value="6">necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates</option>
    <option value="7">rum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
    <option value="8">sum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
    <option value="9">fum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
    <option value="10">aum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
    <option value="11">rtum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
    <option value="12">rumq rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
    <option value="13">rumer rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus</option>
  </select>
</div>
```